# Can I be "clueless of" instead of "clueless about" something?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

The following sentence is correct ([see Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clueless)):

> I'm clueless **about** something

But can you also say:

> I'm clueless **of** something

?

Comment: Ciao, Marco! Do you have any clue which one might be correct? Hint: look up "clueless" in a dictionary and most of them will have sample sentences.

Comment: @δοῦλος is a nice way to tell me this type of question does not fit into here?! :-)

Comment: No, Marco. It's a nice way to say that we encourage learners to use an English dictionary... If you do that, you have a skill to help you when there is no one around to ask. The ODO is popular: [clueless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clueless). I provide the link in case you don't know about this dictionary. And here is a link to [clueless](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/clueless) in the Cambridge Learners Dictionary. The sample sentence has your answer, if you look for the clue.

Comment: Marco, I think it's a nice way of saying that users are expected to do a little research first – and, if you have done research already, please share what you found and explain why you are still confused. You're welcome to ask questions, but your questions will be better received if you follow the guidance posted [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: Sorry guys, I understand what you mean. I didn't know the Oxford dictionary was offering some help for free. Thanks for the hint. I updated my question.

Comment: *Clueless of* is used sometimes. Looking at some examples, it seems that *clueless of* is equivalent to *ignorant of*. And *clueless about* means *have no knowledge about*. This is the easiest way to show the difference in a comment. If I can prepare a good answer, I will. But sometimes prepositions are learned through observation and not by any  rule that can be memorized or that will work in every case. At least that is my excuse for being clueless of (=ignorant of) such a rule. (Note that *clueless about* would *not* sound as good in the previous sentence--at least to me.)

Comment: In other words, sometimes *about* and *of* are interchangeable and sometimes they are not. And sometimes which verbs they work with is changing, and sometimes not every native speaker will agree on a usage. In general, *clueless of* (when it means "ignorant of*) seems to be a fairly recent usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to say that "about" and "of" are equally valid from a technical point of view. That said,

[image]

gives a pretty good idea of which one will sound more natural.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clueless+about%2C+clueless+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclueless%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclueless%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I thought the attribution was automatically carried along.

Answer (score 1):

*X of Y* means that X is part of, attached to, belonging to, or a subset of Y in most cases.

> This is the finger of my hand.
>
> I am the king of this realm.
>
> I have 4 of the 10 marbles.

So saying *I am clueless of X* implies that X has one of the relations to you above, but you didn't notice.

> Look, you have six fingers.  Wow, I sure was clueless of that finger.
>
> Your Highness, did you not know you ruled this area?  No, I was clueless of this territory.
>
> I have all 10 marbles.  Um, I see 11 in your hand.  11?  I sure was clueless of that extra one.

*X about Y* means that X is near and freely moving through Y (but not attached), that X knows information on Y or information on how to do Y. Since *clueless* can means you don't know about something, *about* will be what you want to use if you just mean not knowing knowledge or a fact.

> I am clueless about biology.
>
> I am clueless about playing marbles.
>
> I am clueless about what happened yesterday.  Fill me in.

Though anyone in speech or reading would probably know what you meant irrespective of the preposition you use, so it's probably not a big deal.

> I was clueless about that speed bump.  Sorry!
>
> I was clueless of that speed bump.  Sorry!

Comment: Interesting! Besides they would understand me anyway, in the phrase/context of your example, is it wrong to write "No, I was clueless **about** this territory"?